# Optaplanner ConstraintStream doesn't work

Tags: java, stream, scheduler, optaplanner, rostering

I'm making an aircraft mechanic scheduling program using Opta Planner. So far, we have added many hard, soft, and medium constraints, but one does not work.

The constraints are the same as the code below.

```
private Constraint workPerMonth(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(MechanicAssignment.class)
        .groupBy(MechanicAssignment::getEmployee
        , MechanicAssignment::getWorkDate
        ,ConstraintCollectors.min(MechanicAssignment::getFlightWorkStartDateTime)
        ,ConstraintCollectors.max(MechanicAssignment::getFlightWorkEndDateTime))
        .groupBy((employee, work , min, max ) -> employee
        ,(employee, work, min, max ) -> work
        ,(employee,work, min,max ) -> workCodeCheckUtil.getWorkHour(workCodeCheckUtil.matchWorkCode(min, max)))
        .join(OffWork.class, Joiners.equal((employee, work, totalWorkMinute) -> employee.getEmpNo(), OffWork::getEmpNo))
        .filter((emp, work, totalWorkMinute, off) -> !off.getWorkCode().equals("WVC"))
        .groupBy((emp, work, totalWorkMinute, off) -> emp
        ,(emp, work, totalWorkMinute, off) -> Pair.of(work, totalWorkMinute)
        ,ConstraintCollectors.countQuad() 
        ,ConstraintCollectors.sum((emp, work, totalWorkMinute, off) -> (work.getIndexDay() == off.getTargetDate().getDayOfMonth()
        && work.getIndexMonth() == off.getTargetDate().getMonthValue()) ? 0 : 1   
        ))
        .groupBy((employee, work, offCount, notOff) -> Tripe.of(employee, work.getKey().getIndexMonth(), offCount)
        , ConstraintCollectors.sum((employee, work, offCount, notOff) -> notOff == offCount ? 1 : 0) 
        , ConstraintCollectors.sumLong(
            (employee, work, offCount, notOff) -> work.getValue()/60)
        // , ConstraintCollectors.countQuad()
        , ConstraintCollectors.countQuad()
        )

        .filter((employee, offCount, totalWorkMinute, assignCount) -> {

            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().withMonth(employee.getSecond());
            YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from(localDate);

            LocalDate lastDate = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth();

            int leftDay = lastDate.getDayOfMonth() - assignCount;

            int realOff = employee.getThird() - offCount;

            if ( realOff*8 + (totalWorkMinute + ((leftDay - 9 - realOff) * 4)) > 171)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        })

        .penalize(HardMediumSoftLongScore.ofHard(2))
        .asConstraint("cannot work more than 171 hours per month");
    }
```

**Explanation of Constraint**

> `realoff` : actual off count
> `totalWorkMinute` : Actual working hours
> `leftday` : The number of days in a month minus the actual number of days worked
>   realOff*8 + (totalWorkMinute + ((leftDay - 9 - realOff) * 4)) 
>  When calculating this experession at last filtering function It should not exceed 171hours.

**Result**

> Testing confirmed that there were datas that were exceeded 171 hours, but I confirmed that  constraints were not violated. What am I doing wrong?

Since the group by function has more than 4 keys, I tupled it through the Pair and Tripe user interface.

Comment: Please provide a specific executable test case and I may look into it when time permits.